# iOS payment for services options

Tags: ios, payment

We have built an Android app that allows us to purchase tokens now to pay for services in the future and are looking at the best way to implement this same thing in an iOS app. We've considered doing this as a web app but there is native functionality that we need as well so that's not an attractive solution.

Lets say the app is for beauty services

- There is a map of participating salons
- In the app, you can buy beauty tokens
- When you find a salon you like, you can use tokens to purchase
  services
- 2 tokens for a manicure from Salon A
- 4 tokens for a massage from Salon B
- 3 tokens for a haircut from Salon C
- Add an extra token for a tip at each location

Is there a way to allow users to purchase these tokens in an iOS app so that Apple doesn't treat this as an in-app purchase and charge 30%?

We'd prefer to keep this seamless and not make the user exit to a website to make the purchase but the margins on the service aren't high enough to support giving away 30% of each purchase.

Thanks in advance - 
Dan

Comment: You can't use In-app purchases for these services.

Answer (score 1):

Apple offers two payment services, but the terms on each might require some modification to your business model to comply:

- In App Purchase (IAP) is [for purchase of "digital" goods and services only](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#physical-goods-and-services) — that is, for "stuff" that happens entirely in your app and not in the real world. So you'd probably get in trouble with App Review if you tried to use IAP to buy tokens exchanged for real-world goods/services.
- Apple Pay is for real-world goods and services, and doesn't cost 30%, but is also [for real-world money only](https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/get-started/), not virtual tokens. So it's likely not what you're looking for either. However, Apple does [claim to be working with merchants to support rewards programs](https://www.apple.com/pr/library/2015/06/08Apple-Pay-Giving-Shoppers-Even-More-Ways-to-Pay.html), which sounds pretty similar to your use case, so it might be worth reaching out to them via the contact options on the afore linked developer pages.